# React js - apply Regex in forms

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a React Application that have a register but I am having a problem about implementing the Regex into password field.

What I want to happen is apply my regex formula to the password so when I clicked the Submit button and it didn't meet the requirement related to my regex it will error in console and if passed it will print pass in the console.

Here is my regex formula:

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})"
```

And here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    }
  }

  handleUsername = (event) => {
    this.setState({ 
      username: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handlePassword = (event) => {
    this.setState({ 
      password: event.target.value
    })
  }

  submitButton = () => {
    console.log(this.state.username)
    /* I don't know what to put here, maybe the condition if password
    meets regex requirements */
  }

  render () {
    const { username, password } = this.state 
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          placeholder="Username"
          onChange={this.handleUsername}
          value={username}
          name="username"
        /><br />
        <input 
          placeholder="Password" 
          onChange={this.handlePassword}
          value={password}
          name="password"
        /><br />
        <button onClick={this.submitButton}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should evaluate your event.target.value before setting it to password like this or alternatively you can put your your regex in a variable and use same pattern

```
handlePassword(event){
    if(event.target.value.match("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})")!=null) {
      this.setState({password: event.target.value});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you must add an `onInput()` property to Password field, which is used to validate the password. 
Then you must set a `state` to check whether the `regex` is satisfied or not.

You can use this state as a condition in the `submitButton()` to display the desired output in the console.

The code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      pass: false,
    }
  }

  handleUsername = (event) => {
    this.setState({ 
      username: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handlePassword = (event) => {
    this.setState({ 
      password: event.target.value
    })
  }
  handleValidate = (event) => {
    var pass = event.target.value
    var regex = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})"
    var test = regex.test(pass)
    if (test) 
        this.setState({pass: true})
    else 
        this.setState({pass: false})
  }

  submitButton = () => {
    console.log(this.state.username)
    if(this.state.pass)
        console.log(this.state.pasword)
    else
        console.log("Error")    
  }

  render () {
    const { username, password } = this.state 
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          placeholder="Username"
          onChange={this.handleUsername}
          value={username}
          name="username"
        /><br />
        <input 
          placeholder="Password" 
          onChange={this.handlePassword}
          onInput={this.handleValidate}
          value={password}
          name="password"
        /><br />
        <button onClick={this.submitButton}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```